# TFS2012 wiki.htm file in new team project

Tags: tfs, agile, wiki

Whenever I create a new team project in TFS2012 I get a wiki.htm file appear in the shared documents folder (it is blank).

What do people do with it?

Is there something on the sharepoint portal that will produce it automatically or is it a something where you just add your own HTML when required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a wiki file, you can update it as you would with any other type of wiki file. if you don't add any data to it, it will remain empty.